# How to set the same background image for all components in React Native?

Tags: image, react-native, background, components, react-native-navigation

Good morning, everyone. I start in native react and I would like to put the same image in my mobile application, I make for each screes (page) a  which makes my image load each time I change screens, what I want to do is put the same image and load it for all the components so the image loads only once for all the screens

what I did was create a background.js component that contains a  that I export and import into other screens, but it doesn't work

Here's what I did in background.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TextInput,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    AsyncStorage,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Dimensions,
    ImageBackground, ScrollView, StatusBar
} from 'react-native';
import Service from '../../service/base';
import bgImage from '../../assets/ToG.jpg'
import {Header} from "react-native-elements";

const service = new Service();

const { width : WIDTH } = Dimensions.get('window');

export default class Background extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.f}>
            <ImageBackground source={bgImage} style={styles.bgImage}>

            </ImageBackground>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

and then I import it into the other screens

```
import React from 'react';
import {
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TextInput,
    KeyboardAvoidingView,
    AsyncStorage,
    TouchableOpacity,
    Dimensions,
    ImageBackground, ScrollView, StatusBar
} from 'react-native';

import bgImage from '../../assets/ToG.jpg'
import Background from './Background'
import {
    Image,
    Header,
    Button,
} from "react-native-elements";
const {width : WIDTH} = Dimensions.get('window')
export default class Classement extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Background>
                <ScrollView>
                    <Header leftComponent={{
                        icon: 'menu',
                        size: 30,
                        color: '#fff',
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        onPress :() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer(),
                    }}
                            centerComponent={{ text: 'TOG', style: { color: '#fff' } }}
                            backgroundColor= "transparent">
                    </Header>
                    <StatusBar
                        barStyle="light-content"
                        animated={true}
                        backgroundColor="#6a51ae"/>
                    <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='padding' style={styles.wrapper}>
                        <View style={styles.container}>
                            <Text style={styles.header}>Matchs</Text>
                            <Text style={styles.text}>
                                Bah y a rien à montrer p'tit chat, t'attends quoi pour rentrer une feuille de match ?                            </Text>
                        </View>
                    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
                </ScrollView>
            </Background>
        );
    }
}
```

ça ne marche pas

the result is a screen, the image loads but the component itself no longer loads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to add `{this.props.children}` in your `Background` component to render what you are passing in the `Background` component from the `Classement` component.

You can look at this question, which they are doing something similar [What is {this.props.children} and when you should use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706823/what-is-this-props-children-and-when-you-should-use-it). The documentation for that is here https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment.

Hope it can help you!

Comment: Thanks..I read the documentation and understood the concept but as my use is not the same as on tutos, it doesn't work well. could you help me with a sample code