# Limit child components in a react component

Tags: reactjs

i have a question, i'm not sure if possible or not.
Here is a sample code.
I have a component, i want everytime they use my component and a children 
it should only accept the specific component.

for e.g:

```
<tableComponent>
   <tableHeaderComponent/>
   <tableHeaderComponent/>
   <tableHeaderComponent/>
</tableComponent>
but for this type it should not be accepted
<tableComponent>
   <th>blah</th>
   <th>blah2</th>
   <yourowncomponent/>
</tableComponent>
```

thanks,
ping pong

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706823/what-is-this-props-children-and-when-you-should-use-it this can be perfect solution for you

Comment: Well, I'd say that just documenting the intended use case and not providing any support outside that use case should be enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assign a `displayName` to the component you want to allow and check inside the parent component if the children have the allowed `displayName`

```
const Good = () => <h1>Good</h1>;

Good.displayName = "Good";

const Bad = () => <h1>Bad</h1>;

const WithGoodOnly = ({ children }) => {
  let allowed;
  if (Array.isArray(children)) {
    allowed = children.every(child => child.type.displayName === "Good");
  } else {
    allowed = children.type.displayName === "Good";
  }

  return allowed ? <div>{children}</div> : null;
};
```

rendered

```
const App = () => (
  <WithGoodOnly>
    <Good />
  </WithGoodOnly>
);
```

rendered

```
const App = () => (
  <WithGoodOnly>
    <Good />
    <Good />
  </WithGoodOnly>
);
```

not rendered

```
const App = () => (
  <WithGoodOnly>
    <Good />
    <Bad />
  </WithGoodOnly>
);
```