# React native not passing props between components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a simple container component that should handle some logic at some point:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text, View, Button, Image} from 'react-native';
import Title from '../Presentational/Title';

class AppList extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return (
        <Title titleProperty={'To Do Something'}></Title>
      );
    }
  }

  export default AppList;
```

I try to pass some `props` to a `Title` component so that component would display them:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native'

export default class Title extends React.Component {
    render() {
        const {children} = this.props.titleProperty;

    return (
        <View style = {styles.header}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>{children}</Text>
        </View>
    )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    header: {
        backgroundColor: 'skyblue',
        padding: 15,
    },
    title: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        color: 'white',
    },
})
```

The result I'm getting is a blue bar without any text

[imgur link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3a5FD.png)

Why is it not working?

Comment: Try removing curly brackets around `children` in declaration. Like, `const children = this.props.titleProperty`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is not working is because in `Title.js` you are trying to get value of `titleProperty` incorrectly.

`const {children} = this.props.titleProperty;` implies that you want to store value of `this.props.titleProperty.children` inside `children` constant.

what you should do is read value of `titleProperty` and then it will it display correctly in your component.

You can do this in various ways, few of them are listed below

- `const children = this.props.titleProperty;`
- `const { titleProperty } = this.props;`

In the first option you can read `titleProperty` from props and assign it to any named variable you want. In the later option it will read the value of key from `this.props` and only assign the value of key is present otherwise `undefined`

[Find output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aU2Pl.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
const {children} = this.props.titleProperty;
```

In this way you're trying to deconstruct the `titleProperty` which should be an object and should have the `children` property.
More about destructuring on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

I am not sure if you are confused with the `children` props of React, in this case I recommend you to read this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49706920/9013688