# React Component access Props

Tags: reactjs, react-component, tsx

Is it possible to access the inner property of a React Component?

Examples of React Component usually show prop types as HTML/XML inner properties:

```
<MyComp paramOne='val1' paramTwo='val2' />
```

The class for that would be:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export interface MyCompProps {
    paramOne: string;
    paramTwo: string;
}

export interface MyCompState {

}

export class MyComp extends React.Component<MyCompProps, MyCompState> {
    public render() {
        return <div>
            <ul>
                <li>paramOne: {this.props.paramOne}</li>
                <li>paramTwo: {this.props.paramTwo}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

Is it though possible to access `val3` in the following example code?

```
<MyComp paramOne='val1' paramTwo='val2'>val3</MyComp>
```

Comment: Yes, that would be the [`children`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706823/what-is-this-props-children-and-when-you-should-use-it).

Comment: I am not sure if I understand correctly but I think that `val3` can be accessed as `this.props.children` inside `class MyComp`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `val3` would be accessible via the `children` prop.

```js
export class MyComp extends React.Component<MyCompProps, MyCompState> {
    public render() {
        return <div>
            <ul>
                <li>paramOne: {this.props.paramOne}</li>
                <li>paramTwo: {this.props.paramTwo}</li>
                <li>children: {this.props.children}</li>
            </ul>
        </div>;
    }
}
```

```js
<MyComp paramOne='val1' paramTwo='val2'>val3</MyComp>
```