# What is the children variable in Gatsby? How could I assign that to another component?

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

I'm trying to make a small blog with Gatsby, but there is something in my index.jsx that I'm not able to understand.

There is a variable that is defined like this:

`const { children } = this.props;`

When rendering, that represents the lastest post. But I can't figure out where I assign that prop. For example, when I'm rendering a header component I pass the props like this:

`<Header myProps="someValue" />`

But, How could I do that with the index? Is not in the index where you call all your components with their props?

This is my index.jsx file:

```js
import React from "react";
import Helmet from "react-helmet";
import Navigation from "../components/Navigation";
import config from "../../data/SiteConfig";
import "../styles/main.scss";

export default class MainLayout extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    return (
      <>
        <Helmet>
          <meta name="description" content={config.siteDescription} />
          <html lang="en" />
        </Helmet>
        <Navigation menuLinks={config.menuLinks} />
        <main>{children}</main>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

See? I use `{ children }` in the index, but how does Gatsby know what is that variable if I never pass the prop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is {this.props.children} and when you should use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706823/what-is-this-props-children-and-when-you-should-use-it)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Gatsby allows to query for content i.e. children components in various ways. You did not specify what starter or theme you are using which might be important for your question.

> See? I use { children } in the index, but how does Gatsby know what is that variable if I never pass the prop?

Some plugin or theme inside your code base is providing the children props to your index component. Go through your `gatsby-config.js` and `gatsby-node.js` and look for components that inject data.

This [tutorial](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-five/) explains how to provide data to components. As an example, one way to pass data as props to a template component is using the [node API](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/tutorial/part-seven/):

```
// gatsby-node.js

  result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({ node }) => {
    createPage({
      path: node.fields.slug,
      component: path.resolve(`./src/templates/blog-post.js`),
      context: {
        // Data passed to context is available
        // in page queries as GraphQL variables.
        slug: node.fields.slug,
      },
    })
  })
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I checked `gatsby-config.js` and `gatsby-node.js` files and after some time trying to understand what I was reading I finally found how was that prop been passed.

I'm using the Gatsby Advanced Starter by the way. Maybe I shouldn't have gone with something called "advanced", but I could't help it.