# Why to use props.children in React

Tags: reactjs

I was learning React and came across props`.children` and asked myself why it was created and what problems it came to solve. After some research, I understood that `props.children` is best to be used when we want to pass JSX to a certain component. Then, I asked myself again if `props.children` is used to pass JSX as props to a component then isn't it also OK to pass props like this: `myProp={<div><SomeComponent>Some String</div>}`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is {this.props.children} and when you should use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706823/what-is-this-props-children-and-when-you-should-use-it)

Comment: @norbitrial, yeah I read about it could not get EXACT answer. thus I decided to ask.

Comment: The children prop is the ReactNode that is wrapped by your component. It's more convenient to use children than to have to create a new prop and pass JSX to that, and it allows a comparable approach to building components.