# Adding child components in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, jsx

I want to add children elements in the `demo` element of the `Wrapper` component

```
function Wrapper() {
    return (
        <div className="demo">Something</div>
    )
}
```

```
<Wrapper>
    <span>This is something</span>
</Wrapper>
```

But this doesn't work!
What is the correct way to do so?

Comment: Where the demo element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with `children` prop

```
function Wrapper({children}) {
    return (
        <div className="demo">{children}</div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is to call [`{props.children}`](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html#containment)

```js
function Wrapper(props) {
  return (
      <div className="demo">{props.children}</div>
  )
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Wrapper>
      <span>This is something</span>
  </Wrapper>
, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root" ></div>
```

From @Soroush Chehresa's answer to [What is {this.props.children} and when you should use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706823/what-is-this-props-children-and-when-you-should-use-it)   say that:

> `this.props.children` does is that it is used to **display whatever you
> include between the opening and closing tags when invoking a component**

Answer (score 0):

change your wrapper component to this:

```
function Wrapper({ children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="demo">Something</div>
      {children}
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As in your wrapper function just add children as argument, because wrapper function needs to consume something to provide you something, so just pass children to wrapper function that internally render your children passed as argument

```
function Wrapper({children}) {
    return (
        <div className="demo">{children}</div>
    )
}
```