# Insert image within imported React component (SOLVED!)

Tags: reactjs, image, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

**(SOLVED, see answer below)**

I want to add an image inside each accordion section and I've tried to use `<img src={Image}/>`. If that piece of code is placed as in the screenshot it works, but it's located outside of the **< Accordion >**.

If I move the code inside **< Accordion >** it stops working and I can't figure out exactly how to fix this. A thought was to somehow use image like `{props.title}` and `{props.content}` but could not get it to work.

Any suggestions?

[code in component **FirstAccordion.js**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vENQ.png)

**Accordion.js** // component with the accordion logic

```
return (
        <div className="accordion-section">
            <button className={`accordion-button ${setActive}`} onClick={toggleAccordion}>
                <p className="accordion-title">{props.title}</p>
                    <Chevron
                        className={`${setRotate}`}
                        width={10}
                        fill={"#777"}
                    />
            </button>
        
            <div 
                ref={content}
                className="accordion-content"
                style={{ maxHeight: `${setHeight}` }}>
            
            <div
                className="accordion-text"
                // the prop dangerouslySetInnerHTML makes it possible to use HTML within a string
                dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.content }}  
                />

            </div>
        </div>
```

**FirstAccordion.js** // component in which I import accordion logic

```
export function FirstAccordion() {
    
    return (
        <>
        <Sidebar />
        <Navbar />
        <h1 className="h1-accordion">Pregnancy Week By Week</h1>
        <section className="accordion-background">
        <div className="accordion-wrapper">
        <div className="accordion-container-cne">
            <Accordion
            title="Week 1"
            content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua."/>
```

Comment: It appears that your `Accordion` component needs to accept the `children` prop if you wish to surround HTML/React components in JSX. For example: ```<Accordion>Hello</Accordion>```, the string "Hello" would be accessible as `props.children` or `children` (if you're using ES6 destructuring) within the Accordion component. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49706823/what-is-this-props-children-and-when-you-should-use-it) for more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this:

```
<div
  className="accordion-text"
  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.content }}
/>
```

Too:

```
<div className="accordion-text">{props.children}</div>
```

You should then be able to use the accordion like this:

```
<Accordion title="Week 1">
  <p>Hello World</p>
  <img src={...} />
</Accordion>
```

You probably have to adjust to your needs.

Comment: Late reply, but thank you! Got it to work with help of this!